# Can't resolve DNS or Ping outside the firewall but can remote in via SSLVPN

Tags: networking, internet

I don't understand why or how this can happen.

We use 2 separate LAN's, 1 for computers and servers, the other for VOIP phones. They are not connected in any way. They are connected to the same ComCast modem using the same internet connection.

Our computer LAN goes down occasionally, but this doesn't ever affect the phones OR remote access to the computer LAN via SSLVPN. This has been happening for the last 4 days.

The internet goes up and down and yet the phones are still functioning.

Any ideas why this would happen? they have two entirely different firewalls

Thank you in advance

Comment: If they're on two separate lines and only one line is failing, the issue would be internal to that line.

Comment: They aren't on two separate lines, just two separate lans going out through the same internet connection. Those lans are behind their own firewalls.

Comment: So they share a line, but on different "LAN"s? Do you mean different VLANs?

Comment: @root maybe two physical lans connected to the same perimeter. I vote up for switching firewalls, test in on weekend. you will know if something messed up with you server/pc firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by performing some simple ping tests from within the network:

```
1) Perform ipconfig and ping returned gateway IP.
2) Ping inside interface of firewall. (skip if same as #1)
3) Ping outside interface of firewall. (assigned public IP)
4) Ping ISP provided gateway IP.
5) Ping 8.8.8.8.
```

I'd suspect the issue is likely firewall related. You may want to update firmware and double check your NAT/firewall rules.

Comment: I know for cerain that 1 and 2 work fine. I did not attempt to do 3 or 4, and 5 fails every time we go down. I will let you know what 3 and 4 yield when it happens again.

Comment: Okay, 3 and 4 work fine as well even when 5 is not working. Any suggestions?